# QGIS Clip function in Raster layer Style Single band pseudocolour not working?

Tags: qgis, raster, clip, display

I've been using  QGIS for a while and recently upgraded to 2.4, but now find that displaying raster layers is difficult. In particular, the clip function (tick box bottom left of "Style">"Singleband pseudocolor" menu) does not seem to be working. This makes it difficult to display a number of layers together.

To specify the problem: I wish to display cells with values ranging between 20-200 on a layer where values range between 1 and 200, and would have added values 20 and 200 into the window and ticked the "Clip" box in previous versions, but this no longer works. All cells with values 1-200 are displayed.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't reproduce your error. If I load a SRTM file and set the Min and Max to 100 and 200 and use clip to MinMax, only areas with heights between those values are black.

Comment: Thanks Andre for your reply. To confirm: you used the "singleband pseudocolor" option from the drop-down menu?

Comment: Sorry, I took "singleband gray". You are right, between QGIS 2.2 and 2.4 the clip-checkbox became useless. Have you tested the latest dev version too? If the problem remains, you might open a ticket for it.